# Why does Ecto.Repo process not need `send/receive`?

Tags: elixir, ecto

When making database queries using Ecto we will use something like `Users.Repo.get!(id)`, this of course works, but why do I **not** need to `send/receive` to communicate with the `Users.Repo` process? Why can I just call it as simple as referencing the module and function name?

`Users` is an OTP Application, where `Users.Application` has the `Users.Repo` process loaded as children to the `Users.Supervisor` process

```
  ...

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      Users.Repo,
    ]
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Users.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Users.Repo` gets `Ecto.Repo` injected with [`use Ecto.Repo`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#content) and hence default `get/3` implementation is [delegated](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.5.5/lib/ecto/repo.ex#L325-L327) to [`Ecto.Repo.Queryable.get/3`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.5.5/lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex#L61-L63) and then down to [`adapter.execute/5`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.5.5/lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex#L229).

`adapter` in turn is already a [`GenServer`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.5.5/lib/ecto/repo/registry.ex#L17-L21) and `execute/5` is an interface to the process called behind the scene. That abstraction level is required to encapsulate connection pool, timeouts, error handling, etc for you.